Find current in R1 using Thevenin theorem
Please help me find the current in R1 using Thevenin theorem.

I am especially confused on how to find the Thevenin voltage.


Use Thevenin with V2, R2 and RL. Then you can calculate current in R1.

@velvet please I have updated my solution so far. I just don't know how to solve for the thevenin voltage. Please help

Please help @Antonio51

@velvet Please can you help solve the question and send to my mail please emartu40@gmail.com

@velvet my solution so far is to add the internal resistances and subtract the voltages then Vth = V - IR where V is the difference between the V1 and V2 and R is the sum of  R1and R2 but then I can't find I.

Rth looks good. Next, you need to find Vth. And because V2 > V1 the current will flow from V2 to V1. This current is equal to  I = (20V - 10V)/(10ohm + 20ohm) = 0.334A. With this knowledge are you now able to find Vth?

There is 10 volts between the left of R1 and the right of R2: -

And clearly (due to the values of R1 and R2 and, RL being disconnected), one-third of 10 volts is across R1. This means that the Thevenin voltage is 13.333 volts.
You have already established the Thevenin resistance as being 6.666 Ω.
So, when you reconnect the load resistor RL, it forms a potential divider from 13.333 volts via the Thevenin resistance (6.666 Ω and itself at 40 Ω). That means that the voltage across RL is 11.429 volts.
This means that there is 1.429 volts across R1 and you can now calculate R1's current. I'll leave that up to you.

Thanks I understand it now

@EmmanuelAnah if we are done here, please take note of this: What should I do when someone answers my question. If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.
